# The requested address is not valid in its context when connecting to BluetoothSocket

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to connect to a socket using Bluetooth in Windows 10. The code looks like this:

```
var services = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(new Guid("e2645167-6352-4429-b0db-45a36f424ebc"))));
if (services.Count > 0)
{
    // Initialize the target Bluetooth BR device
    var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(services[0].Id);

    // Check that the service meets this App's minimum requirement
    if (SupportsProtection(service))
    {
        _service = service;
        try
        {
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(_service.ConnectionHostName, _service.ConnectionServiceName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The application fails in the `ConnectAsync` method. The exception message only says `The requested address is not valid in its context`.

Comment: Have you already run this sample? (note the /dev branch): https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs